# How to make the Python3 interpreter faster or the fastest possible?

Tags: gcc, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization, cpython

As the title says, how to make the python3 interpreter which executes python programs; faster or even the fastest possible using the vanilla CPython versions available at www.python.org; in any linux distribution?

Is there a way to make it even faster than the default "--enable-optimizations" compiler flag?

Which compiler to use to achieve the goal?

What supportive benchmarks to corroborate assertions on compiler choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found a way but it only makes it slightly faster from my benchmarks.

I did it by doing the following things:

1. Extending the profiling for PGO to all 425 regression tests that
   comes with the python3 source.  Configuring "--enable-optimizations"
   only runs a small subset of the 425 regression test that comes with
   the Python3 source.
2. Adding CFLAGS="-march=native -O3 -pipe" with LTO via "--with-lto"
   configure option
3. Adding "-fprofile-update=prefer-atomic" to the profiling stage
4. Adding "-fprofile-partial-training" to the final Feedback Directed
   Optimisation (FDO) stage.

**How to do the above and what are the consequences?**

***First, the results...***

[image]

Picture paints a thousand words as they say!

- The red python has all points 1-4 above done.
- While the green python only has points 2 with the stock
  "--enable-optimizations" configuration which does the limited PGO
  subset.

Lower is better.  So you can see the majority of wins goes to the red python with several wins to the green python.

Pyperformance was used for the benchmarks which has a focus on real-world benchmarks, rather than synthetic benchmarks, using whole applications when possible.

https://pyperformance.readthedocs.io/index.html

And it was graphed using pyperfplot.

https://github.com/stefantalpalaru/pyperfplot

The endeavour wet my appetite so I did several more benchmarks which took a full day to do....
[image]

- Red and yellow pythons are the same as the red and green from the
  previous graph.
- Green python is Python3.9 from Ubuntu's repository compiled by them
  using gcc9.3.
- Light Blue python is Clang12 with point 2 above with the stock
  "--enable-optimizations" configuration which does the limited PGO
  subset.  It is the **worst** performer of the lot in the benchmarks!
  Surprising really I started this endeavour thinking Clang-12 would
  win out with all the recent publications and advertising going around
  with Linux now fully LTO'able and Clang-12 dominating first place
  wins in many Phoronix benchmark articles in the last couple of
  months.
- Dark Blue is the default Ubuntu Python3.8 that comes from the
  repositories.  Added here just to show if there's been progress from
  3.8 to 3.9 and to compare with my custom builds.

So **How to do the above 4 points and what are the consequences?**

1. Get the python3 version you want to build, I got 3.9.6...

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tar.xz
```

2. Decompress...

```
tar -xf ./Python-3.9.6.tar.xz
```

3. Go to the directory and configure it.

```
cd ./Python-3.9.6
```

For gcc

```
time CFLAGS="-march=native -O3 -pipe" ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-lto
```

For clang

```
time CC="clang" CFLAGS="-march=native -O3 -pipe -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality" ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-lto
```

The extra options for clang is just following the official advice from the python devs here... https://devguide.python.org/setup/#clang

4. At this point you would traditional start building/compiling.  However we want to further customise how the build will be with the extra options during profiling and during final release build.

```
nano Makefile
```

Search for "PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG" (ctrl+w)
And append after a space "-fprofile-update=prefer-atomic" without the quotes.  It should look something like...

```
PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG=-fprofile-generate -fprofile-update=prefer-atomic
```

5. The next line underneath should say "PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG"; it affects the final release build/compile append "-fprofile-partial-training" after a space at the end without the quotes. It should look something like...

```
PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG=-fprofile-use -fprofile-correction -fprofile-partial-training
```

**Note** *that this point is only compatible with gcc*.  "-fprofile-partial-training" is **not** available to clang-12 at the time of this writing.  Without this setting, gcc will 'optimise for size' code paths that were not part of profiling.  Enabling this setting will make gcc optimise code paths not profiled, to be 'optimised for speed' aggressively which can lead to better performance but at the cost of larger code size.
see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

6. Finally we extended the list of regression tests to run from the stock subset to the full set of tests.
   While still in "nano Makefile" search for "PROFILE_TASK=    -m test --pgo"
   and replace it with:

```
PROFILE_TASK=   -m test --pgo-extended
```

7. Now you can start the build.  Note however that enabling the full suite of tests for profiling will **massively increase the amount of time** needed to build Python3 to completion.

```
time make -j$(( $(nproc) + 1 ))
```

The -j formula in the command above just figures out the number of cpus you have and adds 1 for multiprocessing of the build/compile/linking to speed it up.

The regression tests though will be executed sequentially unfortunately with no easy way of switching to a concurrent way of running the tests.
It will run 425 tests profiling all of them!

On my i7-3770 it took this long...

```
real    49m26.882s
user    55m1.160s
sys 2m1.106s
```

But I did have a few other programs and applications and a VM running at the same time.

8. Once done, "altinstall" so you do not mess up the default python3 that comes with your distribution which can cause problems.

```
sudo make altinstall
```

9. If you have multiple custom built python versions use update-alternatives to manage them.

```
sudo update-alternatives --verbose --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.7 374 --slave /usr/local/bin/python3-config python3-config /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config
sudo update-alternatives --verbose --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.8 382 --slave /usr/local/bin/python3-config python3-config /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config
sudo update-alternatives --verbose --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 396 --slave /usr/local/bin/python3-config python3-config /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config
```

Use the following command to configure which is the default "python3"

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

This is mine...

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/local/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/bin/python3.9   396       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/pypy3             369       manual mode
  2            /usr/local/bin/python3.7   374       manual mode
  3            /usr/local/bin/python3.8   382       manual mode
  4            /usr/local/bin/python3.9   396       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Lastly, something to note is that any python3 in "/usr/bin" belongs to your linux distribution.  Try not to mess with it as it can mess things up later.  All your altinstalls will got to "/usr/local/bin".

**Some Conclusions...**

- Clang, an awesome compiler and project, is bad for python3, well at least with my setup.  Perhaps if their devs are reading this, they can do something about it.
- GCC rules Python3, I haven't got Intel's compiler (ICC?) so don't know, but I hear it is even better when used to build python3.
- The tweaks stated above and outlined have made my default python3 faster and snappier overall, however it took a LOT of time to build it!  It is worth it in my opinion.

---

**UPDATE:**
**Python 3.10.0
vs
ubuntu 20.04 stock python 3.8.10**

Python 3.10.0 with Full PGO, Partial Training, Prefer-atomic, march=native (zen3 R7-5800X), O3 optimisation
**Clear wins --> 33**
Python 3.8.10 Ubuntu stock from repos
**Clear wins --> 22**

However looking at the graph you can see that where 3.10 lost out to 3.8.10 stock from Ubuntu repos, some of the magnitudes are quite big.

[image: Python3.10-Zen3Native-PGO-PartialTraining-PreferAtomic.VS.Stock-Python3.8.10]

Comment: Have you tried training your PGO builds on your own Python programs that you care about having it run quickly?  i.e. tune CPython for the actual input you want it to handle fast.  I'd expect some regression tests to exercise lots of corner cases that are rare in real code (e.g. throw an exception), so you'd want to *avoid* those as being misleadling to the profiling that will guide optimization.  But I'm not familiar with CPython's source tree or tests, so maybe it's fine.

Comment: Not easy without hacking away significantly the build process that comes out of the box.
The goal was to find something anybody can do, although lengthy, is still simple (the steps above)

Comment: Ideally if the Python3 devs added "pyperformance" - https://pyperformance.readthedocs.io/index.html; to the extended regression test, then perhaps we could get better FDO!

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate the build process doesn't have an easy way to replace the training runs with your own script.  x264's PGO build options let (and require) the user supply videos to encode if you want to use PGO.

Comment: Interesting you mention that, I just wrote a similar one for HandBrake but using HandBrake's out-of-the-box build process idiosyncracies...
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655387/134742

Comment: Excellent answer with those extra PGO tweaks! I've tried a similar approach, but been surprised to not get much speedup vs the distro provided python 3.8 (Ubuntu 20.04). When looking into it, I noticed that Debian/Ubuntu and clearlinux seem to hack in some patches to improve performance, so unfortunately it's not just about compiler flags or PGO. E.g. proper linking with AVX support <https://github.com/clearlinux-pkgs/python3/blob/master/0003-AVX2-and-AVX512-support.patch> which might help boost data science libs.

Comment: @JPvRiel When I did the above I did it on an Ivybridge i7 which doesn't have AVX2 no AVX512.  just AVX v1.  

I haven't tried the above yet on anything newer.  I've got a zen3 now so I suppose I should try the above when time permits.  The experiment above took a full day though, so a bit difficult to find that time atm.

Comment: @DanglingPointer, indeed a lot of work. I wrote a bash script to automate the build/complile and a python script to inspect from distutils what "magic sauce" Debian/Ubuntu use with CFLAGS, etc, but in the end struggled to untangle it. I must be doing something wrong because even with `-march=native -O3` and the full PGO profiling, on ave, my custom compile doesn't beat Ubuntu's overall. I wins on some benchmarks, but loses out on others. Not sure if 03 causing more memory use/size might be a factor.

Comment: @JPvRiel - What CPU were you using when you tried the benchmarks?

Comment: @DanglingPointer, Intel i7-9750H which supports AVX2

Comment: @JPvRiel I have updated the bottom of the answer with a graph and some obvious commentary for py 3.10 with all the optimisations vs stock ubuntu py 3.8.10.
I can see what you are saying that some of the losses are quite significant in magnitude but overall I still got more 1st places for 3.10